# jquery getting an 'undefined' on the id of a div element I'm trying to grab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase-realtime-database

So I am dynamically generating HTML code with JavaScript that loads in all my images from my Firebase Realtime Database. I'm currently working on implementing a button attached to each image that will delete this image when clicked. However, after multiple attempts to grab this div's ID attribute using both standard JavaScript and Jquery, the id in the alert box is always 'undefined'. Inspecting the webpage allows me to see that the image's id is always loaded in just fine, so I know it is there.

[This is the HTML Generated that I'm trying to interact with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3sRN.png)

JavaScript function to respond to my html 'onclick event'

```
function deleteFile(){

var postId = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
alert("You have selected id: " + postId);
var sure = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this post?");
 if(sure){
    firebase.database().ref().child('Posts/' + postId).remove().then(function(){
        alert("Post deleted sucessfully");
      });
    }
  };
```

Attached image is what html is generated on the actual chrome inspector. The ID's of course will all be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `this` parameter on your html onclick attribute so it become `deleteFile(this)`

then on your js

```
function deleteFile(element){
    var postId = $(element).closest('div').attr('id');
    alert("You have selected id: " + postId);
    var sure = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this post?");
    if(sure){
        firebase.database().ref().child('Posts/' + postId).remove().then(function(){
            alert("Post deleted sucessfully");
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, the ID is now showing up, and the post is able to be deleted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Pairing onclick with `$(this)` won't work as you expect because `$(this)` has a different context, you could view its value using `console.log($(this));`

**What should be done is add a class to that button and bind an onclick event via jquery.** Run snippet below.

- Red div contains onclick event attached via jquery.
- Yellow div contains onclick event attached to the button attribute onclick.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".getIdButton").click(function() {
      alert($(this).closest("div").attr("id"));
   });
});

function getId() {
  alert($(this).closest("div").attr("id"));
  console.log($(this));
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}

#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="red">
  <a href="#">Just a link</a>
  <button class="getIdButton">Click Me</button>
</div>

<div id="yellow">
  <a href="#">Just a link</a>
  <button onclick="getId()">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: So after implementing this code, which makes total sense to me, nothing happens. There are no errors, nor does the alert pop up anymore.

Comment: @sazar97 what class did you use? I modified the jquery code and placed it inside document.ready(). Your content must be dynamic hence the event wasn't attached at page load.

Comment: the code now runs after your modification. I was thinking that the code being dynamically loaded must've been why it wasn't being interacted with. So thank you! And my button has a class of imageButton so I utilized that one when implementing your code.